# Android 'CordovaWebViewClient' - 'shouldOverrideUrlLoading' is not getting called

Tags: android, cordova

I am working on the cordova Android and iPhone app. So far the apps are working fine. But now I want to run the app with using my server url instead **index.html** in config.xml. For that I did the following change in config.xml
 Here 'abcxyz.com' is my server url.
Its working fine in iPhone app and all the plugins are also working. :).
But in Android, The app is loading fine, but **CordovaWebViewClient** is not getting called in the Android native side. My app is needed the communication between the javascript and native android side.

Please help me why the CordovaWebViewClient method 'shouldOverrideUrlLoading' is not getting called for the custom urls. how can I fix that.?

Thanks in-advance...

Answer (score 0):

In config.xml did you added this.

```
<access origin="*" />
```